# Link to another Page via href link and toggle a hidden Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to click on a link on site1 that leads to site2 and if the link has been clicked the hidden text (here: text_1_toggle) on that page should be visible.

P.S. I'm pretty new to this topic..so forgive me if i don't understand your answers right away :)

site1:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="site2.htm#text_1_toggle">Click me!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

site2:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="toggle.js"></script>
  <style>
        h4:hover
        {
            cursor: pointer; 
            cursor: hand;
        }
        #text_1_toggle
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
  <div id="site">
      <h4 id="text_1">Text 1</h4>
      <span id="text_1_toggle">     
      1 some text...
      </span>

    <h4 id="text_2">Text 2</h4>
      <span id="text_2_toggle">     
      2 some text...
      </span>   
  </div>
</body>
```

toggle.js

```
jQuery("#site").ready(function()
{
  jQuery("#text_1").click(function()
  {
    jQuery("#text_1_toggle").toggle();
  });    

  jQuery("#text_2").click(function()
  {
    jQuery("#text_2_toggle").toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to check click event on  site1 link and then use that variable on site2. See this for more info: http://www.xul.fr/javascript/parameters.php

Answer (score 0):

The effect that you've described can be achieved with CSS.

You need to use the `:target` pseudo selector for the element you'd like to display. This will give you the option of being able to style (including setting the `display`) the `#text_1_toggle` element when you use this hash in the URL, for example the following can be added to your CSS:

```
#text_1_toggle:target {
    display: inline;
}
```